# Distance between intersection of circle and 2 lines

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry

[image]

I feel like this should be simple, but I am unable to find any solutions. I am trying to find the distance between the 2 points (red line) where a circle of radius r intersects 2 lines, given the angle between the lines.

How can I find the 2 intersecting points?

Comment: Intersects ? You mean tangents, probably.

Comment: Consider the isosceles triangle of equal sides r, forming an angle π-α.

Comment: The two lines were acting like tangent to the circle. If we know the line equation then we can find the perpendicular line that passes through the radius.

Comment: looks like distance = 2 * r * cos (alpha/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a mathematical problem, first you can find the slope of your lines using (respectively for degrees and radians):

[image: m=\tan\left(\frac{\alpha}{2\cdot180}\pi\right)]

[image: m=\tan\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)]

Then, writing down the equations for the intersections of the lines and (half of) the circle, you obtain:
[image: m=m^{2}r^{2}-m^{2}y^{2}=q^{2}%2By^{2}-2qy)]

Solving the equation imposing to have a unique solution to have the lines as tangents you obtain the intercept:

[image: q=r\sqrt{1%2Bm^{2}})]

and then:

[image: y_{1}=\frac{q}{1%2Bm^{2}}]

The y of the lower point is just -y1, so the overall distance is, after some simplifications:

[image: 2r\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2\cdot180}\pi\right)] (Degrees)

[image: 2r\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2\cdot180}\pi\right)] (Radians)

[Interactive version](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jm6zqspows)